# Connect SSH and execute script with another user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

In my server I've a script that needs to be executed with the system user (`user1`). I've an SSH user (`user2`) who that one will connect to the server to run the script.

Do you know if it's possible to do it with SETUID, SETGUID? Or I don't have the choice to use:

```
su -c -s /bin/bassh {script} username
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Net up passwordless sudo for user2 on the server
2. `ssh user2@server sudo --non-interactive --user=user1 /path/to/script`